# jquery mobile anchor links in a page

Tags: jquery, mobile, hyperlink, anchor, internal

I would like to link different parts of an html page by using anchor tags and ids in jQuery mobile framework. But it doesn't seem like working like in usual html tags. Here's the code that I tried. Any tips will be appreciated!

```
<div data-role="page">
...
<p> text continues..... 
<id="1"> more text continues..... 
<id="2"> more text continues..... 
<id="3"> more text continues..... 
<id="4"> more text continues..... 
</p>
...
<a href="#1" data-ajax="false">find #1</a>
<a href="#2" data-ajax="false">find #2</a>
<a href="#3" data-ajax="false">find #3</a>
<a href="#4" data-ajax="false">find #4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how mobile techniques affect normal HTML markup, but anchors should be set with `<a name=""></a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<id>` isn't a valid html tag.

You should be using `<a name="one">` as your anchor, and then `<a href="#one">` as your link.

Comment: I didn't eve notice it's an `id` tag instead of anchor... +1

Comment: Thank you, that works! I thought it's a problem with jquery mobile, but i used wrong tags. thanks again.